# Difference between connecting to 127.0.0.1 and server ip

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, php, mysql

I am brand new to php, databases, and linux and had a problem where I could not connect to mysql databse with the php mysql_connection function. When I used the ip address of my VM I kepy getting a connection failure.

After an hour of traversing the directory structure of linux I found /etc/hosts/ and noticed 2 ip addresses. My loopback address and 127.0.1.1. Just for the hell of it I used 127.0.1.1 and I was able to connect to my database and pull the data that I requested. I do not understand  why 127.0.1.1 worked but not the ip of my vm server.

Could some explain what the signifgance is for 127.0.1.1? From what I read it resolves teh hostname of my appliance, but I do not understand what this means.

Answer (score 0):

The IP addresses associated with the network `127.0.0.0/8` are reserved for use for communication within the local machine only.  One of the purposes of this is permit software within a system to use TCP/IP for inter-process communication before any of the physical network interfaces have been configured for TCP/IP.

When server software starts it can pick a specific IP address to be associated with.  As a security feature lots of services will bind to the address `127.0.0.1`, or some ``127.0.0.0/8` network instead of listening for connections on IP addresses associated with the network interfaces.  This makes that particular services only accessible from the system itself.

Mysql on Ubuntu is an example of this.  Within the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` it has a setting in the default configuration of `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`. This means mysql daemon is only usable locally unless you manually change that setting.  Simply commenting the ``bind-address` line out, will make mysql default to listen on all associated IPs with your system.